# Alignment does not display in center in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

This site is displayed properly in chrome, firefox and also IE9. But it does not display properly in IE8.
I tried all thing like margin:0px auto, display : block but it does not display properly.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine in IE8 also

Comment: Your site is pushing IE 8 and 9 into Quirks mode automatically. You'll come across more problems if you don't stop that from happening. That'll be the reason your middle section isn't horizontally centering.

Comment: If you have Internet explorer version is 8, you can see this issue. If you have Internet explorer version is more than 9, Its display properly.The issue is not display is quicker mode.

Answer (score 0):

The site look nice in IE8... write exacty what do you want to change...

Some tweaks that you should make:

- for Search side:

  - add a vertical align for the number in the rounded thing;

`changeSearchForm .number_bg{ display:table;} 
    changeSearchForm .number_bg span { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }`

- make the inputs and inputs images smaller
- use some font awesome icons
- fix the margins for the footer in IE
- if you want to make a circle, all the border with 50%, so it's always a circle, does not matter the with and height.

P.S. Next time work in % for the 'skeleton', base site architecture :)

Answer (score -1):

I am able to see the issues you mentioned in IE quirks mode, actually IE8 is working fine.
Still if you need to fix this issue, Do this -

Add text-align center to the main div(class-skin) or even body tag - this will center the content and then add text-align:left to the content div(class = outter-wrapper) so that again text-align will be set to default for the content.

.skin{text-align:center;}
.outter-wrapper{text-align-left;}

Thanks,
Karthik.